# Не меняется один div на другой, почему?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть некоторая функция у класса в js

```js
push() {
  let card = document.createElement('div')

  card.classList.add('card')
  card.innerHTML = `<h1 id = "Question">Do you remember this word?</h1>\n`;

  card.innerHTML += `<div id = "flipper">
                                <div id = "front" style="display:block">
                                    <p>${toUpper(this.stack.pop())}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div id = "back" style="display:none">
                                    <p>test</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>`
  if (this.stack.length == 0) {
    get_words()
  }

  this.board.insertBefore(card, this.board.firstChild)
  document.getElementById("flipper").addEventListener("click", replace)

}
```

Как можно заметить выше я поставил обработчик на клик блока flipper, в самом обработчике вот такой код:

```
function replace(event) {
    let front = document.getElementById("front");
    let back = document.getElementById("back");
    if(front.style.display == "none"){
        front.style.display = "block"
        back.style.display = "none"
        console.log("Front is visible")
    } else {
        front.style.display = "none"
        back.style.display = "block"
        console.log("Back is visible")
    }
}
```

Обработчик вызывается но на экране ничего не меняется, один блок вместо другого не вставляется.
Ввел в css вот такие свойства для двух блоков:

```
#front {
    background-color: brown;
}
#back {
    background-color: rgb(161, 42, 165);
}
```

И все равно обработчик вызывается, а на экране цвет этих блоков не чередуется, остается коричневым, т. front всегда отображается, не могу понять почему

Суть:
Есть div основной, в котором 2 div(div front и div back) блока, один из которых изначально невидим, по нажатию на основной div, один становится видимым, другой нет и наоборот, сколько не кликай.

Покажу на картинках:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно заметить, что было осуществленно 3 клика и по идее сейчас должен быть блок с текстом test но как бы не так, мы видим блок front.
Могу и весь код показать, просто на мой взгляд он будет мешать, ошибка где-то в этом месте я полагаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//document.getElementById("flipper").addEventListener("click", replace)
card.querySelector("#flipper").addEventListener("click", replace);
```

А лучше:

```
card.innerHTML += `<div class="flipper">
  ...

card.querySelector(".flipper").addEventListener("click", replace);
```

Comment: queryQuery это что?
Если вы имели в виду querySelector, то это не работает

Comment: @АндрейПетров Это работает.